# Getting cookies from local drive in Javascript using Firefox Quantum

Tags: javascript, firefox, cookies

I store some info in cookies in my Javascript code. I have had no problem to set and read them from local drive until Firefox Quantum installed.

Now it seems that the cookies are set (been checked among the cookies), but cannot be read if I open the html file. The document.cookie.length value is always zero. Yet if I set the cookies and refresh the browser (or open the file again not closing the first file) the cookies can be read.

So far Firefox stored and read cookies all right using file:///, but this twist is new for me. Some setting has to be changed, I guess.

Can anybody tell me a solution, how to allow to read the cookies again from local drive?

Thank you.

Comment: I have posted a minimal working example to illustrate what I believe is the same problem in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47426479/cookie-from-local-homepage-lost-between-sessions-in-firefox-57).

Comment: Thanks. Your post is profounder. It is indeed a Firefox Quantum issue. Quick (and best) solution: use Web Storage, as it is mentioned among the last comments in your post as well.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox Quantum (as with Google Chrome and others) has disabled storing cookies for local files due to security issues and other problems. The HTML5 web storage commands are taking over what used to be done with cookies for both server and local web pages. See "https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp"