# Cookie from local homepage lost between sessions in Firefox 57

Tags: javascript, firefox, cookies

(Note: I believe I'm asking about the same problem as [this unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47349152/getting-cookies-from-local-drive-in-javascript-using-firefox-quantum), which is less specific than mine partly because it didn't include an MWE.  Per discussion on [this meta page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267217/why-cant-i-mark-duplicate-questions-which-are-downvoted-not-answered) and [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312285/better-to-reduplicate-or-to-edit-a-poorly-worded-question-with-no-good-answers), I believe it's OK to post a better version of an existing question that has not been answered.)

The following HTML contains an MWE version of a script that worked for years in Firefox but suddenly failed in Firefox 57.0.  The MWE simply displays an integer, incrementing it each time the file is loaded.  The script works in Safari, displaying a different integer each time if I set this file to load when Safari starts.  It works in FF if I repeatedly load the file from the menu using File/Open in the same session.  However in FF 57 it always displays 0 if I load the file when the browser starts.  Examination of `document.cookie` and miscellaneous `console.log()` statements show that this happens because FF 57 loses the cookie between sessions.  Why?

Is this a bug in FF 57?  Is there something subtly wrong with my code that's causing it to fail in FF 57?  Maybe because FF 57 is stricter about Javascript in some way?  (I've checked to see if there's a report about this, but haven't found anything, and have checked to see any of the config settings in Preferences or in `about:config` that might control this behavior, but I haven't found anything.)

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function incrementCookie() {
        lastfooStr = getCookie("foo");

        if (lastfooStr == null || lastfooStr == NaN) { // if first time, start the indexes at 0
            nextfoo = 0;
        } else {
            nextfoo = 1 + parseInt(lastfooStr); //increment it
        }

        setCookie("foo", nextfoo, 365);
        document.write("<head><body>" + nextfoo + "</body></head>");
    }

    function setCookie(cookie_name, value, expire_days) {
        var expire_date=new Date(); // get now
        expire_date.setDate(expire_date.getDate() + expire_days); // expiration date
        var cookie = cookie_name + "=" + value +
                     "; expires=" + expire_date.toUTCString() +
                     "; path=/";
        document.cookie = cookie;
    }

    function getCookie(cookie_name) {
        var doc_cookie = " " + document.cookie;
        var cookie_value = null;
        var cookie_start = doc_cookie.indexOf(" " + cookie_name + "=");

        if (cookie_start != -1) { // found it; now get the value.
            var cookie_val_start = doc_cookie.indexOf("=", cookie_start) + 1;
            var cookie_val_end = doc_cookie.indexOf(";", cookie_val_start);

            if (cookie_val_end == -1) { // must be the last cookie
                cookie_val_end = doc_cookie.length;
            }

            cookie_value = doc_cookie.substring(cookie_val_start, cookie_val_end);
        }

        return cookie_value;
    }

window.onload=incrementCookie();
//-->
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Full disclosure: In FF 57, I get the following (irrelevant, I believe) messages in the console when I run this script:

```
An unbalanced tree was written using document.write() causing data from the network to be reparsed. For more information https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Optimizing_Your_Pages_for_Speculative_Parsing
cookietest.html:48
```

Line 48 is the second to last line of the file; it's the one containing the `</script>` tag.

And:

```
The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.
```

In Safari, I only get this message when I run it:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///favicon.ico
```

Comment: I've seen no issues with cookies in firefox - do you see any errors in the developer tools console perhaps? your code works fine ... oh wait, I see ... `file:///` protocol breaks it

Comment: @JaromandaX: Well, yes.  I don't fully understand them, but but I didn't think they were relevant.  Sometimes browsers complain about crazy things.  I'll add the errors to the question.

Comment: I meant regarding your code - those errors are from 1) malformed HTML (you have no close for head element - and 2) the character encoding one is also irrelevant

Comment: @JaromandaX, Yes, that's what I thought--something like that.  No, there are no other errors.  I'll add the close head--thanks.

Comment: I edited the original comment to mention that the behaviour you describe does indeed occur when the page is loaded using `file:///` protocol - which is not clear in your question (sure, you said "local homepage", but that doesn't mean `file:///` to me :p as my "local homepage" is actual served using http)

Comment: @JaromandaX, right, I understand.  Yes, the homepage load is via `file:///`, as is the menu file/open load, or you can type it into the URL box.  The crucial point is that the cookie is lost between sessions that way.  I haven't tried serving it via a local web server; I don't normally run even a minimal web server.

Comment: if Firefox Quantum has screwed cookies for you that may be the only option!

Comment: @JaromandaX So you don't experience the problem with a local web server, getting the file via http, even between shutdowns of FF?

Comment: no problem using http or https - and I've been using Quantum since it was Beta

Comment: @JaromandaX Huh.  Fascinating.  Weird.  OK, I'll consider that.  I'm not committed to FF in the end, but I've got an elaborate bookmark system, and exporting it to another browser messes it up.  Or might downgrade FF.  Or run a server.  Which is annoying, but not a huge deal in the long run.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: note: `localStorage` survives

Comment: @JaromandaX I didn't know about `localStorage`.  That's great.  Simpler than including cookie-parsing code.  Thanks.  I can be happy again. :-)

Comment: @JaromandaX, while not strictly speaking an answer to what I literally asked, the `localStorage` suggestion qualifies as an answer, and your comments clarified that there's not something I'm doing wrong, and that it is something that's just weird about Quantum.  If you post an answer I'll upvote it, and will accept it unless someone comes in very soon with some deeper info about Quantum (which seems unlikely).